# Exponential or power function in pandasql

Tags: python, pandas

I am combining two dataframes. In selection I need to calculate the exponential/power of a column to get the results.
I have tried few options unsuccessful:

```
from pandasql import sqldf, load_meat, load_births
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
meat = load_meat()
births = load_births()

print(pysqldf("SELECT date, veal * 2 as vealx2  FROM meat LIMIT 10;").head()) #Ok for multiplication and other formulas.
print(pysqldf("SELECT date, veal ** 2 as vealxx2  FROM meat LIMIT 10;").head()) #NOk
print(pysqldf("SELECT date, power(veal,2) as vealxx2  FROM meat LIMIT 10;").head()) #NOk
print(pysqldf("SELECT date, pow(veal,2) as vealxx2  FROM meat LIMIT 10;").head()) #NOk
print(pysqldf("SELECT date, exp(veal,2) as vealxx2  FROM meat LIMIT 10;").head()) #NOk
print(pysqldf("SELECT date, veal^2 as vealxx2  FROM meat LIMIT 10;").head()) #NOk


Error:
PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "*": syntax error
[SQL: SELECT date, veal ** 2 as vealxx2  FROM meat LIMIT 10;]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Above code is only to illustrate the issue.

power of will work  **`X**Y`** in dataframes directly or python code, but not in pandasql.

I could accomplish the result within pandas, but the formula is complex and include conditions, case statements and aggregations which makes the solution very uncomprehend, however very simple as sql statement.

Is there to accomplish exponential or power of in pandasql?

Thanks